# What is date range format for Juriscraper REST API?

Tags: api, rest, datetime

I phrased this question in a specific manner, but I'm more interested in how one generally approaches the problem of figuring out the input parameters for an API. I am trying to filter by date_created__range for the option endpoint in [this API](https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest-info/#opinion-endpoint) and I can't figure out how it wants the date range formatted. They specify that they use the [ISO-8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but I have tried all the following to no avail:

- https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/opinions/?date_created__range=2020-12-01--20-12-10
- https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/opinions/?date_created__range=2020-12-01..20-12-10
- https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/opinions/?date_created__range=2020-12-01/20-12-10

I've also tried with those date ranges reversed. All of these fail with the message `"Enter a valid date/time."` I've even tried downloading the source code for the API and searching through it, but I haven't found anything relevant to this question. How would you go about figuring this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it might be what you're looking for!

https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/opinions/?date_created__range=2013-01-01T00:00:00Z,2013-01-03T00:00:00Z

For reference on process, I just copied one of the dates they used in their example date_modified query
`curl https://www.courtlistener.com/api/rest/v3/dockets/?court__date_modified__gt=2013-01-01T00:00:00Z` and added a second one separated by a comma, since you had already tried dashes, periods, and a slash.